# SQL in Databricks: Only keep oldest records from each month

Tags: sql, date, filter, type-conversion, databricks

I have a table tab1 with several columns including a date column. I want to create a view v1 with only the oldest records for each month and remove any records that came before. Duplicates should be kept and a new month_year column created.

INPUT TABLE tab1

| Provider | report_date | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 20220101 |  |
| Apple | 20220105 |  |
| Apple | 20220120 |  |
| Apple | 20220120 |  |
| Apple | 20220205 |  |
| Apple | 20220210 |  |

OUTPUT VIEW v1

| Provider | report_date | month_year | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 20220120 | 01/2022 |  |
| Apple | 20220120 | 01/2022 |  |
| Apple | 20220210 | 02/2022 |  |

I've used the below code, but it does not work because report_date (yyyymmdd) is an int.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW v1 AS
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  tab1
WHERE
  report_date IN (
    SELECT   MAX(report_date)
    FROM     tab1
    GROUP BY MONTH(report_date), YEAR(report_date)
  )
```

I've tried to cast report_date to char in the SELECT statement part so that the above works, but that gives me an error as well:

```
  CAST(dataset_day_id AS varchar),
```

I've also tried CONVERT function, but I get the following error:

> AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'CONVERT'. This function is
> neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function
> registered in the database 'default'

Comment: You didn't tag your database. Some have this just using 'partitioning'. Also what you are describing doesn't match your sample data, ie: you say report_date is an int but 20/01/2022 is not an int (maybe you are talking about the storage format in the database).

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many producst are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: "keep oldest" and MAX()?

Comment: Then you can group by int(report_date/100). You still didn't tag your database.